# Showing that a website was hit at least $60$ times over a period of $3$ consecutive days

Tags: combinatorics

A website was hit $300$ times over a $15$ day period. I must show that it was hit at least $60$ times over some period of $3$ consecutive days.

I was thinking that it would be best to solve this problem by contradiction and set up three day sections with $59$ total hits, but couldn't get anywhere with this method.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Problems like this can be handled by the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  This is one of my favorite tools in mathematics because of its usefulness and its intuitiveness.  The Pigeonhole Principle states that if you have $m$ pigeons and $n$ boxes (or holes), and you place each pigeon in some box, then at least one box has at least $m/n$ pigeons inside it.  This can also be worded as follows:

Suppose that you have $n$ real numbers $x_1, \dots , x_n$.  Then

$$
x_1 + \dots + x_n = C \Longrightarrow x_i \geq \frac{C}{n} \quad \text{for some } i.
$$

Similarly, if one has $n$ positive real numbers $x_1, \dots , x_n$, then

$$
x_1 \cdot \dots \cdot x_n = C \Longrightarrow x_1 \geq \sqrt[n]{C} \quad \text{for some } i.
$$

The easiest proof of this is probably the proof of the contrapositive:

- If one is given $n$ integers $x_1 , \dots , x_n$, and each of them is less than $\frac{C}{n}$, then

$$
x_1 + \dots + x_n < C.
$$

Comment: +1 I always assumed that the pigeonhole principle was just for the 2-pigeons 1-hole case, i.e. when there are $m$ pigeons and $n$ holes, and $m > n$. I now know the general case!

Comment: @Michael If $m \leq n$, then this is true but not helpful.  For example, if there are $4$ pigeons and $10$ holes, we only know there is at least one hole with $0.4$ pigeons in it!  That sounded way more gruesome than I intended, since we are obviously not splitting pigeons!! (:

Comment: ah, sorry, I was not clear enough. I had only used the pidgeonhole principle to show that two pigeons must be in one hole, not that there must me at least $m/n$ pigeons in one hole.

Comment: @Michael.  Gotcha.  I understand now (:

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

If the hits are $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_{15}$

and $y_1 = d_1 + d_2 + d_3$, $y_2 = d_4 + d_5 + d_6$, ..., $y_5 = d_{13}+d_{14} + d_{15}$.

Can you figure out something about the $y_i$?

Comment: I'm happy to delete my answer if you feel it's close to yours.

Comment: @DJC: No, please don't delete. Your answer is well written (+1 in fact).